# Does the OS Use Memory Address 0x0?

Tags: memory, operating-system, nullptr

My understanding is a typical user program will never use early addresses in memory as these are typically reserved by the OS.
However, does an OS use `0x0` or do even those observe this address as `nullptr`?

Comment: Architecture-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually (at least before *Meltdown*), the kernel *maps* itself in every user-space process virtual addressing space.

Most kernels place themselves in the *higher half* of the memory. This means that the `0x0` address is technically part of the user-space-reserved addressing.

Anyway, given the special meaning that the `NULL` pointer have, the `0x0` address is not supposed to be used by anyone.
Actually, some kernels (e.g. Linux when properly configured) prevent you from allocating anything at the beginning of the address space (including `0x0`). This is intended to be a security measure, in fact, if someone assigns something to the `0x0` address (or following addresses), any *NULL-dereference* bug in the kernel become a dangerously exploitable vulnerability (if other, more recent, security measures, as *SMEP* and similar, are missing).

Answer (score -1):

From the application programmer perspective, on many systems the first page or few pages appear to be inaccessible.

This is normally a function of the program loader. The loader skips the first N pages when it places the application in memory. Thus they have no mapping in the logical address pace. This convention is used to detect stray, null pointer references.

I cannot think of any operating system that reserves these pages. Applications can map the low pages if they desire.

While a typical program "typical" program does not use this address range, an atypical program might.